# CakePhP hasMany not working on different database

Tags: php, database, cakephp, datasource

I'm using the latest CakePHP 2.8 in my system. I'm able to get data from other database in my system, with different datasource, but same connection (user/pass) into my local database server.

I'm able to query the content of the table on different database, but the problem is the has many relation is not showing. But when I'm using the same datasource, the has many working perfectly.

Is it possible to fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried to override the defaultConnection function in your Table class??

If that doesn't work, you will have to create a custom solution.

Comment: Yes, but it won't help